# PHP fatal error on google php api app engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, curl, google-api, google-api-php-client

I've a problem with my app engine while I'm trying to implement Google+ PHP API , it gives me a fatal error in curl file "Goolge_IO.php" it's one of the library files which was provided on https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/

Here's the detailed error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Google CurlIO client requires the CURL PHP extension' in C:\Users\joker\Desktop\\plus\src\io\Google_CurlIO.php:47 Stack trace: #0 C:\Users\joker\Desktop\plus\src\Google_Client.php(106): Google_CurlIO->__construct() #1 C:\Users\joker\Desktop\plus\index.php(22): Google_Client->__construct() #2 C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\php\setup.php(100): require('C:\Users\joker\...') #3 {main} thrown in C:\Users\joker\Desktop\plus\src\io\Google_CurlIO.php on line 47
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open config file in - > google-api-php-client/src/config.php

on line 38 , You'll find :

```
// Which Authentication, Storage and HTTP IO classes to use.
```

Under it replace with this code :

```
// Which Authentication, Storage and HTTP IO classes to use.
'authClass'    => 'Google_OAuth2',
'ioClass'      => 'Google_HttpStreamIO',
'cacheClass'   => 'Google_MemcacheCache',

// We need to configure fake values for memcache to work
'ioMemCacheCache_host' => 'does_not_matter',
'ioMemCacheCache_port' => '37337',
```

Answer (score -1):

You want to read the Error again

```
'Google CurlIO client requires the CURL PHP extension'
```

Have you installed cURL? If you're running a Linux system, you want to use something like

> apt-get install php5-curl

On Windows, assuming you're using something like XAMPP it will already have the cURL plugin existing in the files, and you'll want to uncomment the line

> ;extension=php_curl.dll

from your php.ini file.

Comment: This does not apply to AppEngine.