# Google PHP API Client requires the CURL PHP extension

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-api-php-client

I'm using php on appengine to login to g+ according to this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow)
and I get this error

`Google PHP API Client requires the CURL PHP extension`

I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848700/php-fatal-error-on-google-php-api-app-engine) but I get the same error

Comment: Is curl installed and enabled? Check phpinfo.

Comment: I do not know why the solution on http://stackoverflow.com/a/19851839/2018227 does not work for you, I have used it myself, and it works on AppEngine.

Comment: The instructions are on the gae-php-tips blog, google for it.